# Convert SQL to HQL?

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

How can I convert the following SQL query into HQL?

```
SELECT  count(sa.AID)
     FROM   A  sa 
  , B sal,C  m 
  WHERE sa.AID = sal.AID(+) and   sa.BID = m.BID and sa.AID ='0001'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to transfer each `table`/`column` into it's associated `Entity`/`Class` in JAVA, then build the query with Hibernate ORM as below.

Suppose 
- The entity name for the table `sa` is `saEntity`, for the table `B` is `bEntity`, and for the table `C` is `cEntity`.
- The class name for the column `AID` is `AidClass`, and for the column `BID` is `BidClass`

Then the Hibernate ORM query can be written as per the following (I like formating HQL queries inside annotations on multiple lines to make it easier to read & adapt).

```
@Query( "SELECT COUNT(sa.AidClass) "
      + "FROM saEntity sa, "
      + "     bEntity sal "
      + "     cEntity m"
      + "WHERE sa.AidClass = sal.AidClass"
      + "  AND sa.BidClass = m.BidClass "
      + "  AND sa.AidClass ='0001'")
public List <?> runMyQueryMethod();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try looking at the answer to this question.

[HQL to SQL converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768798/hql-to-sql-converter)

Or this article may help..

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=972441

If you showed some of the mappings I could probably help with the HQL. You could just use

Session.CreateSQLQuery instead??

Comment: But i had gone through the above i didnt get answer

Comment: It looks like simple cross joins to me but with the mappings that would help :)