# NHibernate find SQL select in the decompiled project

Tags: c#, .net, sql, nhibernate

I have a project decompiled in IlSpy and code below. Where can I find the raw SQL query? How criteria.List() know which select use to?

```
    protected object ListOne(ISession session, DbBaseArgs args)
    {
            ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(((DbListArgs)args).DbType);
            criteria.SetMaxResults(1);
            for (int i = 0; i < ((DbListArgs)args).DbExpressions.Count; i++)
            {
                if (((DbListArgs)args).DbExpressions[i] is Order)
                {
                    criteria.AddOrder((Order)((DbListArgs)args).DbExpressions[i]);

                }
                else
                {
                    criteria.Add((ICriterion)((DbListArgs)args).DbExpressions[i]);

                }
            IList results = criteria.List();
            object result;
            if (results != null && results.Count > 0)
            {
                result = results[0];
            }
            else
            {
                result = null;
            }
            return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Decompiling does not help you to find the raw SQL Query. You can try to add a log for the logger named  `NHibernate.SQL` at the debug level and you should see in the appender configured the queries issued to the database. For example add in the log configuration something like:

```
<logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="NHibernateSQLFileLog"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: is it a user type NHibernate.SQL? I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are to

1. [Run your app and view the log](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate.aspx).
2. [Write a bit of code to get the SQL to be generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704462/how-can-i-have-nhibernate-only-generate-the-sql-without-executing-it).
3. Try [NHProf](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/NHProf)

(from linked answer):

```
public String GetGeneratedSql(ICriteria criteria)
{
    var criteriaImpl = (CriteriaImpl) criteria;
    var sessionImpl = (SessionImpl) criteriaImpl.Session;
    var factory = (SessionFactoryImpl) sessionImpl.SessionFactory;
    var implementors = factory.GetImplementors(criteriaImpl.EntityOrClassName);
    var loader = new CriteriaLoader((IOuterJoinLoadable) factory.GetEntityPersister(implementors[0]), factory, criteriaImpl, implementors[0], sessionImpl.EnabledFilters);

    return loader.SqlString.ToString();
}
```