# NHibernate query extremely slow compared to hard coded SQL query

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm re-writing some of my old NHibernate code to be more database agnostic and use NHibernate queries rather than hard coded `SELECT` statements or database views.  I'm stuck with one that's incredibly slow after being re-written.  The SQL query is as such:

```
 SELECT
    r.recipeingredientid AS id,
    r.ingredientid,
    r.recipeid,
    r.qty,
    r.unit,
    i.conversiontype,
    i.unitweight,
    f.unittype,
    f.formamount,
    f.formunit
   FROM recipeingredients r
   INNER JOIN shoppingingredients i USING (ingredientid)
   LEFT JOIN ingredientforms f USING (ingredientformid)
```

So, it's a pretty basic query with a couple JOINs that selects a few columns from each table.  This query happens to return about 400,000 rows and has roughly a 5 second execution time.  My first attempt to express it as an NHibernate query was as such:

```
var timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
timer.Start();
var recIngs = session.QueryOver<Models.RecipeIngredients>()
   .Fetch(prop => prop.Ingredient).Eager()
   .Fetch(prop => prop.IngredientForm).Eager()
   .List();
timer.Stop();
```

This code works and generates the desired SQL, however it takes 120,264ms to run.  After that, I loop through `recIngs` and populate a `List<T>` collection, which takes under a second.  So, something NHibernate is doing is *extremely* slow!  I have a feeling this is simply the overhead of constructing instances of my model classes for each row.  However, in my case, I'm only using a couple properties from each table, so maybe I can optimize this.

The first thing I tried was this:

```
IngredientForms joinForm = null;
Ingredients joinIng = null;
var recIngs = session.QueryOver<Models.RecipeIngredients>()
   .JoinAlias(r => r.IngredientForm, () => joinForm)
   .JoinAlias(r => r.Ingredient, () => joinIng)
   .Select(r => joinForm.FormDisplayName)
   .List<String>();
```

Here, I just grab a single value from one of my JOIN'ed tables.  The SQL code is once again correct and this time it *only* grabs the `FormDisplayName` column in the select clause.  This call takes 2498ms to run.  I think we're on to something!!

However, I of course need to return several different columns, not just one.  Here's where things get tricky.  My first attempt is an anonymous type:

```
.Select(r => new { DisplayName = joinForm.FormDisplayName, IngName = joinIng.DisplayName })
```

Ideally, this should return a collection of anonymous types with both a `DisplayName` and an `IngName` property.  However, this causes an exception in NHibernate:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Plus, `.List()` is trying to return a list of `RecipeIngredients`, not anonymous types.  I also tried `.List<Object>()` to no avail.  Hmm.  Well, perhaps I can create a new type and return a collection of those:

```
.Select(r => new TestType(r))
```

The `TestType` construction would take a `RecipeIngredients` object and do whatever.  However, when I do this, NHibernate throws the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'NHibernate.MappingException' occurred
>   in NHibernate.dll
>
> Additional information: No persister for: KitchenPC.Modeler.TestType

I guess NHibernate wants to generate a model matching the schema of `RecipeIngredients`.

How can I do what I'm trying to do?  It seems that `.Select()` can only be used for selecting a list of a single column.  Is there a way to use it to select multiple columns?

Perhaps one way would be to create a model with my exact schema, however I think that would end up being just as slow as the original attempt.

Is there any way to return this much data from the server without the massive overhead, without hard coding a SQL string into the program or depending on a `VIEW` in the database?  I'd like to keep my code completely database agnostic.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `QueryOver` syntax for conversion of selected columns into *artificial* object *(DTO)* is a bit different. See here:

- [16.6. Projections](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-projections) for more details and nice example.

A draft of it could be like this, first the DTO

```
public class TestTypeDTO // the DTO 
{
    public string PropertyStr1 { get; set; }
    ...
    public int    PropertyNum1 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And this is an example of the usage

```
// DTO marker
TestTypeDTO dto = null;

// the query you need
var recIngs = session.QueryOver<Models.RecipeIngredients>()
   .JoinAlias(r => r.IngredientForm, () => joinForm)
   .JoinAlias(r => r.Ingredient, () => joinIng)

    // place for projections
   .SelectList(list => list
     // this set is an example of string and int
     .Select(x => joinForm.FormDisplayName)
         .WithAlias(() => dto.PropertyStr1)  // this WithAlias is essential
     .Select(x => joinIng.Weight)            // it will help the below transformer
         .WithAlias(() => dto.PropertyNum1)) // with conversion
     ...
   .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<TestTypeDTO>())
   .List<TestTypeDTO>();
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot tomorrow!  I'm sure it'll work since your answers always do.  I need to have you on speed dial!

Comment: This works!  I only added two properties for now, but it runs in 7,225ms.  The old code (raw SQL with `IDataReader`) took 6,497ms.  So, it's a *bit* slower but not by much.  Hopefully adding the rest of the properties doesn't slow it down much further.

Comment: So, once I added all nine properties, it got fairly slow (about 27 seconds)..  But on the plus side, I was digging through the source code to `AliasToBeanTransformer` and it occurred to me that I could just implement my own `IResultTransformer` to make the code quite a bit cleaner, so that worked pretty well.

Comment: I have to add one more coment. The power, the reason why I cannot bless NHibernate enough, is the: Extensibility. The native support for custom implementation (custom ICriterion, IProjections, IResultTransformer...) is endless. And while the basic set is really very very large... if needed, you can simply add in custom one. That's outstanding, in comparison with other tools

Comment: Yea, if I could get access to a raw `IDataReader` then I think I could get it running in 6 seconds again..  In this case, I just want NH to build the SQL statement for me and nothing else.

Comment: Maybe also take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704462/. I would not go this way *(because I am trying to do my best to avoid returning more then hundreds records using NHiberante)* but for you it could be another way. (I mean with the `session.CreateSQLQuery("sql")`)

Answer (score 2):

So, I came up with my own solution that's a bit of a mix between Radim's solution (using the `AliasToBean` transformer with a DTO, and Jake's solution involving selecting raw properties and converting each row to a list of `object[]` tuples.

My code is as follows:

```
var recIngs = session.QueryOver<Models.RecipeIngredients>()
   .JoinAlias(r => r.IngredientForm, () => joinForm)
   .JoinAlias(r => r.Ingredient, () => joinIng)

   .Select(
      p => joinIng.IngredientId,
      p => p.Recipe.RecipeId,
      p => p.Qty,
      p => p.Unit,

      p => joinIng.ConversionType,
      p => joinIng.UnitWeight,

      p => joinForm.UnitType,
      p => joinForm.FormAmount,
      p => joinForm.FormUnit)
   .TransformUsing(IngredientGraphTransformer.Create())
   .List<IngredientBinding>();
```

I then implemented a new class called `IngredientGraphTransformer` which can convert that `object[]` array into a list of `IngredientBinding` objects, which is what I was ultimately doing with this list anyway.  This is exactly how `AliasToBeanTransformer` is implemented, only it initializes a DTO based on a list of aliases.

```
public class IngredientGraphTransformer : IResultTransformer
{
   public static IngredientGraphTransformer Create()
   {
      return new IngredientGraphTransformer();
   }

   IngredientGraphTransformer()
   {
   }

   public IList TransformList(IList collection)
   {
      return collection;
   }

   public object TransformTuple(object[] tuple, string[] aliases)
   {
      Guid ingId = (Guid)tuple[0];
      Guid recipeId = (Guid)tuple[1];
      Single? qty = (Single?)tuple[2];
      Units usageUnit = (Units)tuple[3];
      UnitType convType = (UnitType)tuple[4];
      Int32 unitWeight = (int)tuple[5];
      Units rawUnit = Unit.GetDefaultUnitType(convType);

      // Do a bunch of logic based on the data above

      return new IngredientBinding
      {
         RecipeId = recipeId,
         IngredientId = ingId,
         Qty = qty,
         Unit = rawUnit
      };
   }
}
```

Note, this is *not* as fast as doing a raw SQL query and looping through the results with an `IDataReader`, however it's *much* faster than joining in all the various models and building the full set of data.

Comment: Mike seriously, great job. Really. I do have my own Transformer as well. In fact I do use projections mostly for any list view... It is hard to explain "new NHiernate" users how to, what is the best way here or there... if they are asking for a specific question. But you are all the time proving that you really do know what you need and how to do that. awesome. NHibernate is top of the list, king of the hill. You are the proof!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
IngredientForms joinForm = null;
Ingredients joinIng = null;
var recIngs = session.QueryOver<Models.RecipeIngredients>()
   .JoinAlias(r => r.IngredientForm, () => joinForm)
   .JoinAlias(r => r.Ingredient, () => joinIng)
   .Select(r => r.column1, r => r.column2})
   .List<object[]>();
```

Would this work?

Comment: `+1` for this too, though it will just translate the columns into an object array.  However, it seems that's exactly what `Transformers.AliasToBean<T>` is using under the covers anyway.